# How NTP protocol works?

Tags: ntp

I try to find ant NTP documentation for "dummies", I don't understand how NTP works. I need to write an NTP client which should just print current local time. What should I send to the server? What will I receive?

Comment: Can you check this link http://www.abnormal.com/~thogard/ntp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement your own client then you need the [RFC 5905 - Network Time Protocol Version 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905) which specifies the protocol and algorithms of NTP. This document describes exactly what you should send to the server and what you will receive.